# Nodejs - How to act as modbus rtu server

Tags: node.js, npm, modbus

I'm trying to set up a listener that accepts modbus RTU polls.

I have found a lot of modbus related npm library but they are all related to polling from other modbus slave, or act as modbus TCP server. I need to simulate the modbus slave, not the poller (act as modbus RTU server)

Edit: I found this library https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/node-modbus

There is a modbus-rtu-server.js file in the source, so I have been trying to use this. However, I'm having trouble understand and use the library without documentation. Here's what I have tried:

```
const modbus = require('jsmodbus')
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const options = {
    baudRate: 9600
}
const socket = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", options)
const server = new modbus.server.RTU(socket)
server.on('connect', function (client) {
    console.log(client);
});
```

This is what I have so far, but the "connect" event never happened, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Asking for a library recommendation is considered off-topic for this forum.  You can ask how to solve it yourself and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is just waiting for a client to connect. For the *connect* event to happen you have to start a query from a client. That means you need to have a second serial port connected to your `/dev/ttyUSB0` and initiate a Modbus query from it. For that you can use the same library or any other tool like *modpoll* or [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/).

You also need to develop a little bit your server, because right now it does not have any registers defined, so it won't be much use.

Look at the TCP examples, in particular the [SimpleServer](https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/node-modbus/blob/master/examples/tcp/SimpleServer.js). As you can see there, you need to define the Modbus registers or coils on your server, something like:

```
server.on('readCoils', function (request, response, send) {
/* Implement your own */

response.body.coils[0] = true
response.body.coils[1] = false

send(response)
})
```