# modbus-serial, is there a way to open and close the MobusTCP Server?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using the node package [modbus-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modbus-serial) to create a TCP server. I can set up a server like so:

```
var serverExample = new ModbusRTU.ServerTCP(tcpip_parameters, {host: 'x.x.x.x', port: 123, debug: true, unitID: 1});
```

I couldn't find anything about opening and closing a server that has already been created. I was wondering if there is a way to do so like:

```
serverExample.open();
```

However, that throws and error that `open is not a function`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a connection to the server instance it starts listening immediately.

You can see this [issue](https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial/issues/269).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know if there is a way to check if the connection is up currently?

Comment: You should be able to do it with `.on("connect")` event. See [this question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928400/nodejs-how-to-act-as-modbus-rtu-server&ved=2ahUKEwj2ja_5ibjwAhWPmhQKHcuZBF8QFjAEegQIDBAC&usg=AOvVaw21417OjSNybcIrvFWjY6b4).