# Acting as a modbus slave through RTU - communication questions

Tags: node.js, modbus

I am using the following code to simulate a modbus slave device:

```
const modbus = require('jsmodbus')
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const options = {
    baudRate: 115200
}
const socket = new SerialPort("COM4", options)
const server = new modbus.server.RTU(socket)

server.on('connect', function (client) {
    console.log("in connect")
    console.log(client);
});

server.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("in connection")
    console.log(client);
});

server.on('readHoldingRegisters', function (adr, len) {
    console.log("in readHoldingRegisters")
    console.log("adr: " + adr);
    console.log("len: " + len);
});
```

The code above does actually simulate a device. The master I have set up can see a slave device when I run this code. The problem is that I can't seem to get the server functions to reach their `console.log` sections.

I have two theories.

First, my slave device uses the [jsmodbus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmodbus) library to simulate a server and my master device uses [modbus-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modbus-serial) to communicate. Could this cause a problem?

My second theory is that the code I have above is running all at once and doesn't look around or stay open to see future communications. How would I solve this?

I am open to new theories as well. My goal is eventually to pass modbus data back to the master through the `server.on` commands.

**Edit**

I know for sure there is data coming in if I read the data on the serial port directly:

```
socket.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('Data:', socket.read()) //prints incoming buffer data
});
```

I still am not getting data through the server commands.

Comment: hello, have you read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928400/nodejs-how-to-act-as-modbus-rtu-server)? The code in there is tested, it should work out of the box. It does not matter what libraries you use as long as they are Modbus compatible. Your server should be printing the logs as soon as you connect the client and read registers. Are you sure your connections and serial ports are correct? Maybe you can elaborate on that a bit.

Comment: Yes, I used the page you linked to get my project started. I know for sure there is communication because if I read the raw data on the serial port I can see buffer data coming in (I'll edit my question to show). At this stage, I can't see any modbus data coming in through the server.

Comment: I see what you mean. Then the only thing missing is for you to define registers on your server (something similar to what I wrote in my answer). As far as I can tell your 'function` should have three inputs: `function (request, response, send)`

Comment: @MarcosG. I have a `readInputRegisters` function (from the simple server example) but the `send` input comes in as `undefined`. So I'm not sure how to respond back.